# MYSQL queries problems

Tags: mysql

I have created a database and l am trying to pull information from multiple tables.  I was expecting no more than 3 results and l ended up with 15 !!!

Of the 15 results it also duplicated data and also gave wrong data !!

ok here is the statement l ran

```
select *
from [Student, Accomadation_Application
where lname = 'Torrance' 
  and accomodationType = 'flat'
```

Any help would be great dont know if i have supplied enough info..

Comment: Getting to know db schema and content would help.

Comment: Do you have any unique columns? Because if you get 15 results instead of 3, it's very likely that your db table doesn't have `UNIQUE` constraints..

Comment: i just posted a reply underneath this with the contents of the tables

Comment: by unique columns you mean PK ???

Answer (score 2):

Is there some relation between this tables?
You should use something like

```
SELECT *
FROM student
    INNER JOIN Accomadation_Application ON Accomadation_Application.studentId = student.id
WHERE lname = 'Torrance' and accomodationType = 'flat'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect the two tables using the foreign key. A query like this will give you all possible combinations of rows in the two tables.

Something like Student.key = Accomadation_Application.fk - or the other way around.

Comment: l do have the Accomadation table connected with the students table using the primary key from the student table bannerNo.  That is the the FK in accomadation_application im trying to pull records of only people with last name of torrrance who wats a flat but its repeating all 3 people with the surname Torrance 5 times and then giving  me other peoples data with the torrance name beside it ??

Answer (score 1):

You have to join the tables together.

Select * from
Student s
join accomadation_application a
on 
 a.iname = s.iname
where
s.iname = 'Torrance'
and a.accomodationType = 'flat'

(syntax might need to be converted as this is t sql)

Answer (score 1):

Guessing based on what your tables may contain...

```
SELECT *
FROM Student AS s
JOIN Accomadation_Application AS a ON s.bannerNO = a.bannerNo
WHERE s.lname = 'Torrance' AND a.accomodationType = "flat";
```

Comment: the student table ontains bannerNO, fName,lName, DOB, Course  The Acomadation_Application table contains  applicationRef, accomadtionType, durationofStay,applcationDate, bannerNo  with bannerNo being the fk